# Why does my outDir contain a (largely duplicate) src dir?

Tags: typescript

When my project transpiles, I get a structure like so, where src\index.ts gets transpiled into lib\index.js AND lib\src\index.js.  But lib\index.js doesn't seem to get updated on all changes.  Why is that?  Why are there even 2 copies?

```
+---functions
|   |   .gitignore
|   |   config.json
|   |   package-lock.json
|   |   package.json
|   |   tsconfig.json
|   |   tslint.json
|   |   
|   +---lib
|   |   |   index.js
|   |   |   index.js.map
|   |   |   
|   |   \---src
|   |           index.js   *this one seems to be getting compiled*
|   |           index.js.map
|   \---src
|           index.ts
```

My tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you `import` any sources files outside your `src` folder?

Comment: I was trying to import a file from the parent directory of src, messed around and moved the file into src instead and the issue seemed to be resolved.

Came here and saw your comment.  What gave you that insight?

Comment: OK, then my assumption seemed to be correct. I'll give you an answer, when I have time to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lib\src\index.js` is likely a stale output compilation from one of you previous builds, where you also tried to import a file from the parent directory of `src`. The cause is an implicit `rootDir` setting in TypeScript [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

**rootDir**

`rootDir` is relevant to control the output directory structure together with `outDir` option. If you don't set it explicitely, it will be calculated as the common root directory of all your input files - that includes your imported modules. When the compiler writes the output, it determines the output location of every input file like this: Strip off `rootDir` from the input file path and prepend `outDir` to it.

**Example**

Your project root is the `functions` directory. You import everything from `functions/src`, but also one module `functions/foo.ts` (assumed no `rootDir` set). Then:

- `rootDir` is set to `functions`, not `functions/src`
- The output location of `functions/src/index.ts` would be :

  - Strip off `functions` from `functions/src/index.ts` => `src/index.ts`
  - Prepend `functions/lib` => `functions/lib/src/index.ts`

And there you go: output for index.ts will be `functions/lib/src/index.js`. If you want to prevent that, set `rootDir` explicitely to `src` (path relative to tsconfig.json). If somehow not all inputs will be under this folder, TypeScript will complain!

Hope, that helps.